# Show Latest Item only from SPS 2013 List on CEWP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, filter

How to show only the latest item out of multiple items part of SPS 2013 List.

I have set the following filters:

- Field name : Date (Filter rule: Less than or Equal to Today)
- Field name: Publish (Choices: Yes / No) (Filter rule: Contains - Yes)

By default creating a new item will set the date to current date and publish set to Yes by default.
However, the moment when you add another list, it shows then 2 lists on the CEWP flashing on the Homepage.
I want to show only the one that is latest.
Played with all possible filters in the `allitems.aspx` view, but cant find the one that would relate to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a content search web part and set it to return only 1 item and the sort can be on modified desc.

[image]

Comment: I thought of it in past, but on a candid note was a bit confused due to the following reasons.

a) Will it show the entire List Item or only one column of the List?
b) Even setting the sort filter on modified description, wont it show the old message (provided 2 list items modified on the same day / date)

Comment: depending on the display template you are using, it will show the columns. OOTB display templates will give you one column, but it can be easily customized to show everything else. For the sorting, once you configure it to show only one item, it will only show one. it is highly unlikely, two items will have the exact time stamp, but even it happens, it will return one (don't remember off the top of my head if the what the second criteria is)